# What is Sebastian's catchphrase 'A Phantomhive butler who can't do this much isn't worth his salt' in Japanese

Tags: japanese-language, black-butler

In *Kuroshitsuji* (*Black Butler*), Sebastian commonly uses the phrase

> "A Phantomhive butler who can't do this much isn't worth his salt"

It's in about every episode of season one. But it's at least in episode one on 8:38.

I was wondering what this phrase is in Japanese since I can't really make it out from the voice, and I can't find it anywhere else either.

Comment: Hi, could you mention the episode/chapter number for easier reference?

Comment: It's in about every episode of season one. But it's at least in episode one on 8:38. This is a reply to Aki Tanaka's comment, since I can't comment yet.

Comment: While this quote seems popular, looks like it's still missing crucial information about the actual source of this quote. While Vikuotin (who is the OP, created another account due to possibly losing access to their unregistered account) has mentioned that it's on episode 1 at 8:38, it's unclear if this is from the official English dub, English sub, or even fansub. A quick image search of the quote seems it's from Funimation's English sub, but since it's geo-blocked and thus I can't check it, please let me know if this is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian's general catchphrase in Japanese is

> [image]
>
> ファントムハイヴ家の執事たる者、この程度のことが出来なくてどうします?
>
> *Phantomhive-ka no shitsuji-[taru mono](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B), kono teido no koto ga dekinakute doushimasu?*

which can be translated literally to

> Those who are qualified as the butlers of Phantomhive, what would they be if they cannot do this much?

... which actually is straightforward compared to the English translation mentioned in the question.

**However,** that seems like a fan translation, since the official English translation by Yen Press is

> [image]
>
> I am the butler of the Phantomhive Family. It goes without saying that I can manage a technique as elementary as this.
>
> <sup>*Black Butler vol. 1, ch. 1, pg. 8</sup>

Comment: Note: I cannot compare to the official English dub since I don't have access to it. If someone can, it might help to determine if this translation was based on the dub instead or not.

Comment: I can't find Sebastian's usual catch-phrase at the timestamp in the question.  The closest translated line is "Naturally we were able to handle this. We serve the Phantomhive family after all."  (Referring to the creation of the gravel garden.)  Sebastian's usual line in the dub is something close to "If I couldn't do this much for my master, what kind of butler would I be?" (which I think is what the OP is looking for).  The other possibility is something like "You see, I am simply one hell of a butler".  Those are his most oft used lines in the dub.

Comment: I could probably find the exact line in the dub if I had more context since the timestamp doesn't match up.

Comment: I'll see if I can rewatch the first episode later and see what I can find.